# How to resolve python error NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:

Tags: python

When I define data_batch_1_dir and provide a path.

```
import os
data_batch_1_dir = os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/cifar_data/cifar dataset/data_batch_1")
```

then the error shows in the following line that this is not a directory. Please help to resolve it?
ERROR:

```
print('total training batch1 images:', len(os.listdir(data_batch_1_dir)))
```

Comment: Can you verify that the directory exists? Can you run `ls /content/drive/MyDrive/cifar_data/cifar dataset/data_batch_1` in your terminal?

Comment: There's little point using `os.path.join` on a path where you've already hardcoded the separators.